# How to call a contract function only using function hash in ethers.js?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, function-selector

I would like to call a contract function, but I do not have the contract's abi. Since none of the decoders can decode the function name, the only solution I see is calling the function using its hash. Can it be done and how?

I need something like:

```
contract.callingFunc(amount, amount2)
```

,but for 0x9002833f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

Using the [eth_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-ethcall) method, you can call a function using its signature.

Here is an example using `ethers` V5.7.2:

> In this case, we are calling the `poolLenght()` function from the [SushiSwap MasterChef LP staking pool](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc2edad668740f1aa35e4d8f227fb8e17dca888cd#code#L1466) which is a `view` function and returns how many liquidity pairs exist.

```
    function poolLength() external view returns (uint256) {
        return poolInfo.length;
    }
```

- ethers:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "YOUR_ETHEREUM_NODE"
);

function generateFunctionSignature(functionSignature) {
  // generate function signature hash, utils.id uses keccak256
  const functionSignatureHash = ethers.utils.id(functionSignature).slice(0, 10);

  // output results
  console.log(`Function: ${functionSignature}`);
  console.log(`Function signature: ${functionSignatureHash}`);

  return functionSignatureHash;
}

async function main() {
  // Select function
  const functionSignature = "poolLength()";

  const functionHash = generateFunctionSignature(functionSignature);

  // The address of the contract you want to interact with
  const contractAddress = "0xc2edad668740f1aa35e4d8f227fb8e17dca888cd";

  const data = functionHash;
  // Create a transaction
  let transaction = {
    to: contractAddress,
    data: data,
  };

  // Send the transaction
  const poolLength = await provider.call(transaction);
  const poolLengthDecoded = ethers.BigNumber.from(poolLength).toString();

  console.log(`poolLength: ${poolLengthDecoded}`);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

The `generateFunctionSignature` function generates the function selector (also known as the function signature hash) for a given function. It does this by hashing the function signature with the keccak256 algorithm and taking the first 4 bytes (10 characters when represented as a string). This function selector is used by the Ethereum virtual machine (EVM) to identify which function of a smart contract to call.

The function selector is then included in a transaction object. The transaction object specifies the contract to interact with (the `to` field) and the function selector and encoded parameters (the `data` field).

The transaction object is passed to `provider.call`, which uses the `eth_call` method. This won't change any Ethereum network state; it's essentially a read operation.

The result of the call operation is returned as a hexadecimal string. This string is the raw output of the contract function. In this case, the `poolLength()` function returns a number so the hexadecimal string can be converted to a decimal number using `ethers.BigNumber.from`.

> Learn more about the [eth_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-ethcall) method

- Result

```
Function: poolLength()
Function signature: 0x081e3eda
poolLength: 362
```